# I've been working on a smart contract but keep getting Parser Error expected identifier but got 'internal'

Tags: solidity, remix

```
Pragma solidity >=0.6.6

contract Quapura is BEP20('Quapura', 'APUR') {
    /// @notice Creates `_amount` token to `_to`. Must only be called by the owner (QuapuraRouter).
    function mintTo(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(_to, _amount);
        _moveDelegates(address(0), _delegates[_to], _amount);
    }

    /// @notice A record of each accounts delegate
    mapping(address => address) internal _delegates;

    /// @notice A checkpoint for marking number of votes from a given block
    struct Checkpoint {
        uint32 fromBlock;
        uint256 votes;
    }

// contract Quapura is BEP20('Quapura', 'APUR') uint256 _supply, uint256 _txFee;uint256 _lpFee;uint256 _DexFee;address routerAddress,address feeaddress,address tokenOwner,address service) public payable {
        _name = _NAME;
        _symbol = _SYMBOL;
        _decimals = _DECIMALS;
        _tTotal = _supply * 10 ** _decimals;
        _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
        _taxFee = _txFee;
        _liquidityFee = _lpFee;
        _previousTaxFee = _txFee;
        
        _devFee = _DexFee;
        _previousDevFee = _devFee;
        _previousLiquidityFee = _lpFee;
        _maxTxAmount = (_tTotal * 2 / 1000) * 10 ** _decimals;
        numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = (_tTotal * 3 / 10000) * 10 ** _decimals;
        _devWalletAddress = feeaddress;
        
        _rOwned[tokenOwner] = _rTotal;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Swavy89. You need to provide us with the complete code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks scorpion9979 the contract is very long but the other lines do not have issues. After adding the tax fee I started getting that parser error.

Comment: The contract above has so many typos. pragma should start in lower-case, the pragma like should end with a semicolon, and I can see you attempted to comment out "contract Quapura...", you need to comment out the lines below it as well since those are also part of it's declaration.

Comment: The contract included doesn't compile. Please include a minimal version that shows the reported error.

Comment: scorpion9979 and Ismael thanks alot